# Obtener datos solo de algunos objetos soap en android y mostrar en listview

Tags: android, soap

Estoy consumiendo servicios SOAP y este es el resultado que me muestra el soap object:

```
 getContractsByDocSubscriberResponse {
  return = anyType {
    codError = 0;
    msjError = OK;
    dataContracts = anyType {
      contract = 2080086;
      products = anyType {
        commercialPlan = LINEA SOCIO;
        service = 7004 - Telefonía Fija;
        serviceNumber = 4586697;
        status = 3 - Retirado;
      };
    };
    dataContracts = anyType {
      contract = 2175754;
      products = anyType {
        commercialPlan = LINEA ADICIONAL;
        creationDate = 2010 - 10 - 19 T15: 39: 45 - 04: 00;
        cutState = 1 - CONEXIÓN;
        productId = 20175754;
        service = 7004 - Telefonía Fija;
        serviceNumber = 4309189;
        status = 1 - Activo;
      };
      products = anyType {
        commercialPlan = B.A.ADSL;
        creationDate = 2015 - 09 - 09 T15: 42: 47 - 04: 00;
        cutState = 1 - CONEXIÓN;
        productId = 95224313;
        service = 7019 - Internet;
        serviceNumber = 95224313;
        status = 1 - Activo;
      };
      products = anyType {
        commercialPlan = TV CABLE;
        service = 7020 - Televisión;
        serviceNumber = 95135569;
        status = 3 - Retirado;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

La cuestion es que quiero obtener solo los números de contrato y mostrarlos en un listview ya probe otros ejemplos que hay en la pagina pero solo obtengo el primer contrato que esta en el primer dataContracts y no puedo acceder al segundo para mostrarlos ambos en una lista, estoy trabajando con Asyntask y este es parte del codigo del onpostexecute():

```
    Log.d(TAG, "datos contrato: " + resultString);

      SoapObject getProperty0=(SoapObject)resultString.getProperty(0);
                SoapObject getDataOrdenes=(SoapObject)getProperty0.getProperty("dataContracts");
                clientes=new String[getDataOrdenes.getPropertyCount()];

                //inicia datos para listview
                for ( int i=0;i<getDataOrdenes.getPropertyCount();i++ ) {

                    planCom = getDataOrdenes.getProperty("contract").toString();


                    clientes[i]="Contrato: "+planCom;


                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = ne

w ArrayAdapter<String>(ContratoLista.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clientes);

            listView.setAdapter(adaptador);}
```

Comment: Mmm, creo que deberías revisar si el código esta bien escrito.

Comment: Ese es el problema no se donde estoy fallando al obtener los datos.